# Calls to require expect exactly 1 string literal argument

Tags: react-native

I want to render an image based on what what props is passed down. The first commented out filePath is what the source is. I have tried several variations, but it keeps giving me this same error. The react documentation doesn't really cover what you would do on cases where you have 30+ different scenarios. I could just add a state to this component and have it include all the file variations, but that seems like more work than necessary. 
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images

```
 class Weather extends React.Component {
    render() {

    // let filePath = "./weatherimg/01d.png";
   let filePath = `./weatherimg/${this.props.icon.icon}.png`;
   let filePath2 = this.props.icon ? require(filePath) : require(filePath);


return (
  <View >
    <Text>{this.props.location} {this.props.data[0]}</Text>
    <Text>{this.props.data[1]}</Text>
    <Text>Low {this.props.temps.low}, High {this.props.temps.high}</Text>
      <Text>{this.props.icon.description}</Text>
    <View style={{width: 60, height: 60}}>
      <Image source={filePath2} style={{flex: 1}} />
    </View>
  </View>
);
}
}
```

Comment: `let filePath2 = this.props.icon ? require(filePath) : require(filePath);` huh? use the same result regardless of the conditional result?

Comment: My component gets info from the prop which I used to make the filepath. Are temperate literals just not allowed in React-native? Even when I defined the filepath in the higher component that passes it down it doesn't accept it. Shouldn't it just be a string at that point, why are temperate literals a problem in react-native.

Comment: All Im saying is `let filePath2 = this.props.icon ? require(filePath) : require(filePath);` is useless, might as well simplify it to `let filePath2 = require(filePath);`

Comment: It gives the same error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a large list of possible images you can create an `object` that contains all possible images, and then in `Image source` pass the icon name.

```
let icons = {
  'sample1': require('./weatherimg/sample1.png')
  ,'sample2': require('./weatherimg/sample2.png')
  ,'sample3': require('./weatherimg/sample3.png')
}

render(){
  return(
    <Image source={icons[this.props.icon.icon]}/>
  )
}
```

So if `this.props.icon.icon` is `sample1`, it will load that image.

Also you can create a function to validate if requested icon exists or not, and in case of not return a default icon

```
let icons = {
  default: require('./weatherimg/default.png')
  ,'sample1': require('./weatherimg/sample1.png')
  ,'sample2': require('./weatherimg/sample2.png')
  ,'sample3': require('./weatherimg/sample3.png')
}

validateIcons(icon){
  return (icons[icon]) ? icons[icon] : icons['default'];
}

render(){
  return(
    <Image source={this.validateIcons(this.props.icon.icon)}/>
  )
}
```

[This issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6391#issuecomment-194568185) describes that you can`t require dynamic files, and proposes an example on how to deal with it in case that there are few possible options.