# React Native: How can i put variable inside require without giving me an error

Tags: reactjs, react-native

This is the error I get:

```
calls to `require` expect exactly 1 string literal argument, but this was found: `require(image.path)`
```

This is my code:

```
class NewPost extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            uploadPicture: null
        }
    }

  openGallery() {
        ImagePicker.openPicker({
            width: 600,
            height: 400,
            cropping: true
        }).then(image => {
            uploadPictureVar = require(image.path);
            this.setState({ uploadPicture: uploadPictureVar });
        });
    }
}

render() {
  return (
  <View style={styles.imageContainer}>
      {this.state.uploadPicture ?
         <Image
             style={styles.imagePost}
             source={this.state.uploadPicture}
         />
        : null}
   </View>
  )
}
```

I see this question [require() must have a single string literal argument React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47887697/require-must-have-a-single-string-literal-argument-react-native)
But I don't have the string to put in the require I get it when I upload an image.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calls to require expect exactly 1 string literal argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51994329/calls-to-require-expect-exactly-1-string-literal-argument)

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to use it with a variable maybe you can try this trick:

```
uploadPictureVar = require("" + image.path);
```

or

```
uploadPictureVar = require(`${image.path}`);
```

Comment: @FrancoCoronel, I don't what is the real problem but it should work for the `require` part I think. Here is a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/oo1m6nnp06