# How to dynamically create an icon with flatList React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to sent a icon name by using a prop on the list component. So i can set the right icon on the list by giving the prop icon the icon name. My code is looking like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import styled from 'styled-components/native';
import { List, ListItem } from 'react-native-elements';

class ListLi extends React.Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props);
};

renderRow ({ item }) {
    let node;

    React.Children.forEach(item, component => {
        node = component;
    });

  return (
    <ListItem onPressRightIcon title={node} rightIcon={{name:icon}}/>
  )
}

render () {
  const { children, icon } = this.props;

  return (
    <StyledList>
        <List>
          <FlatList
            data={children}
            extraData={icon}
            renderItem={this.renderRow}
            keyExtractor={item => item.name}
          />
        </List>
    </StyledList>
  )
 }
}

export default ListLi;
```

The icon prop contains the name of the icon and i want to render this in the rightIcon `rightIcon={{name:icon}}` any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you can use the answer described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51994329/calls-to-require-expect-exactly-1-string-literal-argument/51995060#51995060)?

Comment: You could make the `icon` property a part of the `item` object within the `children` array, instead of passing it as a prop, and then you could use it as `rightIcon={{name:item.icon}}` in `renderRow()`?

Comment: Could you give an example for this? I'm also trying to send the data like this `data={[children, icon]}` but this gives only 2 items